# How to open a folder that exists inside a zip file with PHP and put content/files inside it

Tags: php

How can one open a folder which exists inside a zip file with PHP, as in the following example:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$tmp_file = tempnam('.', '');
$zip->addEmptyDir($folder);
```

Lets say I want open $folder I have just created so I can put content inside it

Note: `$zip->open ($folder);` doesn't work with me

I want to put my files inside said folder which exists inside said zip file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the docs about [ZipArchive()](http://php.net/manual/de/class.ziparchive.php) you can add an empty directory with [addEmptyDir(string $dirname)](http://php.net/manual/de/ziparchive.addemptydir.php). After that you can use [addFile(string $filename, string $localname)](http://php.net/manual/de/ziparchive.addfile.php) to add files, where `$localname` can be a relative path. Here is an example

```
$folder = 'your_folder';
$file = 'your_file.txt';

$zip = new ZipArchive ();
$zip -> addEmptyDir ($folder);
$zip -> addFile ($file, $folder.'/'.$file);
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, Thank you very much, it's so easy but I'm still biginner, just started learning php few days ago